# How to avoid duplicate entry of Shops in a Website

Tags: database, logic, business-logic

We have a situation like we are unboarding Shops. we don't have any identifier to identify if the shop is already Unboarded. We can not compare by GST No as many shops does not have those.
We only have these data
Name
Address
Pin code
email/phone

But A shop in future can again try to unboard with minor change in name or address and different email/phone. The minor change we are expecting by typing mistakes or abbrebations.

How can I handle this?
I am thinking of comparing all these values in my DB and if any 2/3 matches we will notify we already have an entry.

Can you please suggest any better way?